# epstopdf error in lyx

Tags: lyx, epstopdf

I have read many answers here, but nothing work.
I have an error in my lyx with eps to pdf conversion.
when I use epstopdf in terminal it works, but with lyx doesn't work. 
this is my latex code:

```
    %% LyX 2.1.2 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
yxfsdfcsdf

sdf

sd

fs

df

ds

f\includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{image}

sd

f

dsf

sd

f

d

sfs

fd
\end{document}
```

this is the error message:

```
    Package epstopdf Info: Source file: <image.eps>(epstopdf)                    
date: 2014-10-27 18:32:50(epstopdf)                  size: 14009 bytes
(epstopdf)             Output file: <image-eps-converted-to.pdf>
(epstopdf)             Command: <repstopdf --outfile=image-eps-converted-to.pdf 
image.eps>
(epstopdf)             \includegraphics on input line 32.
system(repstopdf --outfile=image-eps-converted-to.pdf image.eps) executed.
Package epstopdf Info: Result file: <image-eps-converted-to.pdf>.

! Package pdftex.def Error: File `image-eps-converted-to.pdf' not found.

See the pdftex.def package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
```

what is the problem

Comment: Welcome to TeX-sx. We will need to see an example file here: as you are using LyX, what we ideally want is the exported LaTeX. The most usual cause of errors of this type is using the file extension in the name of the graphic, but that may not be it. Do you actually get the converted PDF files created?

Comment: @Seitz You can edit your post at any time, so it's better to edit it and put the code directly there. As well, if you select the new code and click the `{}` button above the edit window, the code will be properly formatted ;)

Comment: Well if it works on the terminal, why don't you simply convert your graphics to pdf before use and includes them normally?

Comment: @Fischer Yes, but i will do this automatically in lyx

Comment: When I use the Grafic tool in Lyx and not the tex comment it works, but the grafic is pixelig

Comment: LyX exports and compiles LaTeX files in a temporary directory that your manually added code is not aware of. You should definitely let LyX do this. Check if there's a mention of image.pdf in `Document>LaTeX log`. Maybe LyX can't find `epstopdf` converter and falls back to eps to png conversion. Show us the LaTeX code (`View>Source`) when you insert the figure by `Insert>Graphics`. Check for all oocurences of `image(.something)` in the log.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the same problem and nothing worked until I changed my directory to a non-`UNC` one. The `UNC` paths are not seemed to be supported by the `epstopdf` package (in my experience).

Comment: Now it looks better actually, thanks @azetina :)